# How to add the html tag into codeigniter variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the following code for display the table row

```
$tableRow="<tr>
           <td style='text-align:center'>".$services[$i]['serviceName']."</td>
           <td style='text-align:center'>".$services[$i]['serviceDesc']."</td>
           <td style='text-align:right'>".$services[$i]['taxAmt']."</td>
           </tr>";
```

But only value is display.I got the following out

```
test tset 43500
```

I want like these

```
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center'>test</td>
<td style='text-align:center'>tset</td>
<td style='text-align:right'>43500</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: did you echo $tableRow;

Comment: You want HTML as output or parsed HTML over webpage.

Comment: On a side note: wrapping the attribute values in single quotes may work, but is technically invalid html and literal strings in PHP are faster with single quotes. You may want to switch them around.

Comment: @user3833740 It's common courtesy here to accept an answer if it helped you. We took time to answer it. You should give back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php function for display your value

```
$tableRow="<tr>
                <td style='text-align:center'>".$services[$i]['serviceName']."</td>
                <td style='text-align:center'>".$services[$i]['serviceDesc']."</td>
                <td style='text-align:right'>".$services[$i]['taxAmt']."</td>
                </tr>";
```

`echo htmlentities($tableRow)`;

Answer (score 0):

replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag inside any variable like :

```
  $a = '<b>hell</b>';
```

then pass the variable to view;

```
$this->load->view('view_name',$a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the literal source of HTML so you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) htmlspecialchars will do a character translation, pasted here for reference

```
Character        Replacement
&                &amp;
"                &quot;
'                &#039;
<                &lt;
>                &gt;
```

You should call it like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($tableRow, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```